# Direct3D device resizing

Tags: c#, resize, direct3d

My application has a panel control associated with a Direct3D device. My problem is that when the panel is resized the backbuffer isn't resized accordingly witch leads to a bad quality in the direct3d display.

How can I handle my panel resizing to set up correctly the device?

Comment: I think you need to recreate the viewport. It's been a while since I did and Direct3D programming, so I'm more than a little rusty (hence why this is a comment and not an answer).

Comment: I think th same. resizing does not work - needs recreation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling Device.TestCooperativeLevel() after the panel resize solved my problem!